# Parallel code compute slow than sequantial code in Matlab

Tags: parallel-processing, matlab

I've next problem with computing time. Time of sequntial compute is faster than parallized code. 
The code compute some matrix expressions. For example, when i compute this code with matrix dimension 3000*3000 time of sequantial computation is about 3.25 sec, but i use more than 1 labs compute time is 5.3-5.7 sec. 
i've 4 cores,ram 3 Gb.

```
sizeOfMatrix = 2000;

MatrixA = rand (sizeOfMatrix, sizeOfMatrix);
VectorB = rand (sizeOfMatrix,1);
StringVectorC = rand (1, sizeOfMatrix);

E = eye (sizeOfMatrix);
An = MatrixA(:, sizeOfMatrix);
An_ = MatrixA(1:sizeOfMatrix-1, sizeOfMatrix);

C_ = StringVectorC(1:sizeOfMatrix-1);
tic

P2 = VectorB * StringVectorC * VectorB * StringVectorC;
P1 = E - P2;

ax1 = P1 * MatrixA;
ax1 = ax1(1:sizeOfMatrix-1,1:sizeOfMatrix-1);

ax2 = An_*C_;
Ax = ax1 - ax2;
Hx = (P1 * MatrixA * VectorB) / (StringVectorC  * VectorB);
Hx(sizeOfMatrix,:) = [];
Asigma = (StringVectorC * MatrixA * VectorB) / (StringVectorC * VectorB);
hs1 = StringVectorC * MatrixA;
hs1(:,sizeOfMatrix) = [];
hs2= StringVectorC * An * C_;
Bsigma = StringVectorC * VectorB;
toc
%disp('Ax');disp(Ax);
%disp('Hx');disp(Hx)  ;
%disp('Hsigma');disp(Hsigma);
disp('Asigma');disp(Asigma);
disp('Bsigma');disp(Bsigma);
```

parallelized code

```
tic
spmd
    sizeOfMatrix = 2000;
    matrixA = rand (sizeOfMatrix, sizeOfMatrix);
    vectorB = rand (sizeOfMatrix, 1);
    stringVectorC = rand (1, sizeOfMatrix);
    MatrixA = codistributed (matrixA);
    VectorB = codistributed (vectorB);
    StringVectorC = codistributed (stringVectorC);
    E = codistributed.eye (sizeOfMatrix);

    An = codistributed( matrixA(:, sizeOfMatrix));
    An_ = codistributed (matrixA(1:sizeOfMatrix-1, sizeOfMatrix));
    C_ = codistributed (StringVectorC(1:sizeOfMatrix-1));
    P2 = VectorB * StringVectorC * VectorB * StringVectorC;
    P1 = E - P2;
    ax1 = MatrixA*P1 ;
    AX1 = gather (ax1);
    Ax1 = codistributed (AX1(1:sizeOfMatrix-1, 1:sizeOfMatrix-1));

    Ax2 = An_ * C_;

    Ax = Ax1 - Ax2;

    Hx = (P1 * MatrixA * VectorB) / (StringVectorC  * VectorB);

    Asigma = (StringVectorC * MatrixA * VectorB) / (StringVectorC * VectorB);

    hs1 = StringVectorC * MatrixA;
    HS1 = gather (hs1);

    Hs1 = codistributed( HS1(1:sizeOfMatrix-1));

    hs2 = StringVectorC * An * C_;

    Hsigma = Hs1 - hs2 ;

    Bsigma = StringVectorC * VectorB;
end
toc
%AX = gather (Ax);
%disp('Ax');disp(AX);
%HX = gather (Hx);
%HX(sizeOfMatrix,:) = [];
%disp('HX');disp(HX);
%Hs = gather (Hsigma);
%disp('Hsigma');disp(Hs);
disp('Asigma');disp(Asigma);
disp('Bsigma');disp(Bsigma);
```

Comment: You are executing nearly the full code on each worker, how should this increase the performance?

Comment: I see you have used a lot of matrix operations like `*`. I believe that Matlab has multi-threaded implementations of these normally. But if you are paralleling your code already, then I think it defaults back to single threaded versions. It is possible that you loose performance like that. But it's more likely that you're just losing to the overhead needed to manage multiple workers.

Comment: i'm beginner in matlab and parallel computing toolbox. could you tell me how should i parallize my code for 4 workers.

Comment: @Dan: You are right http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-multicore.html

Comment: @neruad: I currently don't see a possibility to split your code on different workers. Before spending much time on it: Check your CPU-load (summed for all cores). Because of the mc-implementation this should already be high, thus you can't gain any performance using parallel computing.